# How to restrict the absolut value of each dimention of a sparse gradient from being too large?

Tags: python, tensorflow, sparse-matrix, gradient

Consider the code below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

inputs=tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])
labels=tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None])

with tf.variable_scope('embedding'):
    embedding=tf.get_variable('embedding', shape=[2000000, 300], dtype=tf.float32)

layer1=tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embedding, inputs)
logits=tf.layers.dense(layer1, 2000000)

loss=tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=labels, logits=logits)
cost=tf.reduce_sum(loss)

optimizer=tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
grads, vars=zip(*optimizer.compute_gradients(cost))
for g in grads:
    print(0, g)

grads1=[tf.clip_by_value(g, -100, 100) for g in grads]
for g in grads1:
    print(1, g)

grads2, _=tf.clip_by_global_norm(grads, 10)
for g in grads2:
    print(2, g)
```

The output is:

```
0 IndexedSlices(indices=Tensor("gradients/embedding_lookup_grad/Reshape_1:0", shape=(?,), dtype=int32), values=Tensor("gradients/embedding_lookup_grad/Reshape:0", shape=(?, 300), dtype=float32), dense_shape=Tensor("gradients/embedding_lookup_grad/ToInt32:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int32))
0 Tensor("gradients/dense/MatMul_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1:0", shape=(300, 2000000), dtype=float32)
0 Tensor("gradients/dense/BiasAdd_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1:0", shape=(2000000,), dtype=float32)
C:\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gradients_impl.py:97: UserWarning: Converting sparse IndexedSlices to a dense Tensor with 600000000 elements. This may consume a large amount of memory.
  num_elements)
1 Tensor("clip_by_value:0", shape=(?, 300), dtype=float32)
1 Tensor("clip_by_value_1:0", shape=(300, 2000000), dtype=float32)
1 Tensor("clip_by_value_2:0", shape=(2000000,), dtype=float32)
2 IndexedSlices(indices=Tensor("gradients/embedding_lookup_grad/Reshape_1:0", shape=(?,), dtype=int32), values=Tensor("clip_by_global_norm/clip_by_global_norm/_0:0", shape=(?, 300), dtype=float32), dense_shape=Tensor("gradients/embedding_lookup_grad/ToInt32:0", shape=(2,), dtype=int32))
2 Tensor("clip_by_global_norm/clip_by_global_norm/_1:0", shape=(300, 2000000), dtype=float32)
2 Tensor("clip_by_global_norm/clip_by_global_norm/_2:0", shape=(2000000,), dtype=float32)
```

I know there are two ways to restrict gradients from being too large. `tf.clip_by_value` to restrict each dimentions, and `tf.clip_by_global_norm` to restrict according global gradients norms.

However, `tf.clip_by_value` will cast a sparse gradient into a dense one, which significantly increase the memory usage and decreases the calculation efficiency, just as the warning indicates, while `tf.clip_by_global_norm` will not. Although I can understand why this is designed, how can I restrict the absolut value of each dimention of a sparse gradient from being too large without efficiency decrease?

Please don't tell me just use `tf.clip_by_global_norm`, I know this is ok for most cases, but is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Now I use this, it works well.

```
grads=[tf.IndexedSlices(tf.clip_by_value(g.values, -max_grad_value, max_grad_value), g.indices, g.dense_shape) if isinstance(g, tf.IndexedSlices) else tf.clip_by_value(g, -max_grad_value, max_grad_value) for g in grads]
```